# ReactJS ReactCSSTransitionGroup not adding animation

Tags: animation, reactjs

I've got a new ReactJS app using the React [starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit). I'm trying to animate between views using [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html), but the animation classes aren't being added. What am I missing?

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import styles from './App.css';
import withContext from '../../decorators/withContext';
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles';
import Header from '../Header';
import Feedback from '../Feedback';
import Footer from '../Footer';

@withContext
@withStyles(styles)
class App extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.object,
  };

  render() {
    return !this.props.error ? (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          component="div"
          className="animated"
          transitionName="bounceInLeft"
          transitionEnterTimeout={10000}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={10000}
        >
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {key: this.props.path})}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        <Feedback />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    ) : this.props.children;
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The component looks good. What does the CSS look like? Should be something like this:

```
:global .fade-enter {                  
    opacity: 0.01;                       
}                                      

:global .fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;                          
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;   
}                                      

:global .fade-leave {                  
    opacity: 1;                          
}                                      

:global .fade-leave.fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;                       
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;  
}
```

That is, of course, if you are using CSS Modules. If not, I'd look into the `path` prop and make sure that is being set correctly because the key value is what will trigger the animation enter/leave.

Comment: I think it's an issue with the path property. My keys don't seem to be unique, so the animation classes aren't added at all.